# Power automate data fetch from sharepoint and update

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to automate the leave balance workflow and remove the dependency from the managers to approve it because if the leave is available its available and employees can take it.
I have created a share point where I have mentioned the date , day and leave balance(suppose at one day only 3 people can take a leave so it will be showing as 3), logic I am following, if the leave is greater than 0 in share point then employee can book the leave and an email should sent to the manager plus power automate should create an entry in the same share point that employee XX taken a leave for xyz dates.

In share point I have 3 Columns:
1: Date
2: Day
3: Leave balance

Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: You need to clarify the problem. We’re not here to consult for free and build your solution.

Comment: Thank you and I am sorry this is the first time I am on this platform. The issue is, Power automate is not fetching the multiple rows at the same time :)

Comment: So show your flow in your question. Hard to help without it. More information is required.

Comment: Are you using a Get Items action in your flow setup? Like mentioned by Skin already, can you share more details? Can you for example add a screenshot of the flow setup to your original post?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your responses and this is the first time I am posting something and you guys are awesome.

Its like  a train ticket system.
Suppose we have 2 categories
1: general Quota
2: Sleeper class

When a user book a ticket, user generally get if the ticket is available or not!,If the ticket is showing ( example: 30 tickets available) then user can book that ticket and its auto approved if its not available, user generally look for another day whenever the tickets are available to book the ticket.

Workflow should be: User entered the keyword "Book Ticket"--> gets all the dates when the ticket is available -> user click on book ticket -- if the ticket is available then user should able to book the ticket as the flow will be auto approved.

If the ticket is not available then user get a denial message that ticket is not available for the date and please try some other day.

In share point, I have created 3 Colum's:
1 Date
2: Days
3: Sleeper Quota
4: general quota
5: Available Tickets

I have already created the Bot by power virtual agent and now I want as soon as user selects " Book my ticket" and select General or sleeper quota, user should get the available tickets and can book it by BOT only with out any approval.